# mapStateToProps not updating props when localStorage is modified

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a redux application that requires authentication. Right now I'm trying to make sure the application ensures the user is still logged in whenever they perform an application in the app. Here is the bottom of my App.jsx file:

```
function mapStateToProps({ offline, user }) {
    return {
        // we use this to know if we should redirect to auth pages
        // we don't want logged in users to be hitting these static pages
        loggedIn: !!user.token,
        offline,
    };
}

const ConnectedApp = connect(mapStateToProps)(App);

export default ConnectedApp;
```

I test this functionality by clearing the site local storage through the chrome developer tools. And then performing an action on the site. I've placed many different log statements. I find that `mapStateToProps` is being called, but the props are not changing. The application continues to think that the user is still logged in and the state hasn't changed.

I've been following all the online resources I can find, but nothing seems to be helping. Am I missing something?

Comment: The user token is already in memory when you're clearing the local storage.

Answer (score 2):

That's because `mapState` only re-runs when an action was dispatched to the Redux store, *and* a new store state was calculated as a result.  Modifying local storage does not involve dispatching a Redux action, so your `mapState` will never run.

Don't depend on values from `localStorage` in a `mapState` function - they should *only* extract values from the `state` argument, and return those.

Comment: So if I need to be able to detect when the localStorage is modified, would it be possible to use mapState? Or should I revert to vanilla JS?

Comment: @poctorDepper42 why would you want to detect changes to the local storage?

Comment: No, `mapState` can't and shouldn't have anything to do with `localStorage`.

Comment: @EmileBergeron In a task I was assigned, it was described that if someone cleared their site data, that should be detected so that they could be logged out. Are redux states separate from site data? If so then this whole thing is just a blow-over

Comment: Yes, the Redux store has nothing to do with `localStorage` either, by itself. The most common usages are serializing the Redux store state to `localStorage` based on some store update, or deserializing that store state to initialize the store on app load.  Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43747422/how-to-detect-when-local-storage-is-cleared , it looks like you'd need to listen to a "storage" event in the outer app code, and dispatch an action to clear the Redux store when that happens.

Comment: @poctorDepper42 If the local storage is cleared, they'll be logged out if they navigate to the page again (refresh, restart, etc).